# how can a make android menus?

Tags: android, menu

I am developing an android application and i want to do some menus like this:
https://lh5.ggpht.com/p4TiLyVZjDSMBPacy6iirf9Q3vbpxtTpdwAKlvU03dw6SjaQo1EVNkKIC-nMRzuNRYs

I am talking about the little box that appears over the background calendar. The one which is written Tuesday, October 19, 2010. How can i do this? Is there any view specially designed for this?

Comment: I edited your post to _include_ the image inline, but it seems you promptly reverted it. Keep in mind that your questions are _more_ likely to get answered if everything is contained within your post. Food for thought.

Comment: i didnt want to revert it but i found a mistake in the post and when i was to publish it there was an error that said that i had no reputation to show images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's no view specifically for this behavior.
I would suggest to implement your own specific DialogFragment for that popup with required layout and logic. [Here's](http://arusahni.net/blog/2012/01/implementing-custom-alert-dialogfragments/) an example of such implementation. You can pass coordinates/position to it as arguments to show the dialog at some specific place (use received parameter in fragments onCreateView() to position the layout, calculate margins etc.).

Comment: i think i will be able to do something with that link, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an activity with the theme 'Dialog' applied (in your manifest). This activity/dialog should just contains a listView which display the relevant information.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: but would it appear overlayed to other content or it would be another window?

Comment: It would be another window. But the size will be tinier than the previous window so you will be able to see your content behind.